# Fatal Error: Class 'SELF' not found

Tags: php, class

I have the following relevant code:

```
try {
    self::$db = new PDO($dsn, self::USER, SELF::PASS); //Connect to the database, and store the pdo object.
    self::$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    throw new Exception("There have been an error in the connection: ". $e->getMessage());
}
```

When executing the static function this code is in, I get the following error:

> **Fatal error**: Class 'SELF' not found in **P:ath/to/script.php** on line **107**

I have no idea what might cause this, can anyone please enlighten me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `self::PASS` instead of `SELF::PASS`

Comment: You know that thing when you work on a project for 5 hours straight you can't see what's wrong with your script even though it's so obvious? Thanks for your answer, you answered first so I'll accept your answer, all of you are getting upvotes though :D

Comment: @Truth Oh, I know it way too well :)

Comment: @JuicyScripter problem is, the editor doesn't IMPOSE anything on the code, if you write `self` with SHIFT held, it won't transform it to lowercase ;)

Comment: @Truth, but it may warn you about this ;)

Comment: It did, but it has no way of knowing there isn't a class named `SELF`, which is why it threw the error (since there isn't :P).

Comment: Ehm, PHP is not case-sensitive. Specifically class names are not. It's just the `self` keyword which is treated as such (and not in all contexts).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Ever tried PHPStorm? It knows if a class exist or not, and warns you that the class does not exist.

Comment: Could you tell my, why on my xampp server (windows 10, PHP Version 5.6.15) SELF make no warning, no error - just simply working? I would like to got some warning or error, becouse, the same code doesn't work on production linux server.

Answer (score 3):

First line `self` and `SELF` isn't the same thing...

```
self::$db = new PDO($dsn, self::USER, self::PASS);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using lowercase? self::PASS instead of SELF::PASS.